# How do I notify askers that they are using an outdated version of an API (such as OpenGL)?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

### Background

Many beginners to the 3D graphics inadvertently start using "Legacy OpenGL" (versions 1.x)  instead of the newer "Modern OpenGL" (versions 3.x/4.x). The new API introduces many new features and improvements and is almost always the recommended version to use. The difference between the two is readily apparent when OpenGL code samples are posted.

### Question

What is the proper way to respond to questions asking about Legacy OpenGL (or another outdated API) where the person asking does not seem to be aware of modern alternative or its advantages?

**Edit:** I should add that the a significant portion of tutorials and information about OpenGL on the internet only deal with Legacy OpenGL and never mention Modern OpenGL at all. Furthermore, these questions are asked by people just learning the API, and who are very likely learning from these outdated resources. Wouldn't we be doing them a disservice by teaching them the basics of the old API, without ever saying that it is long since obsolete?

To give an idea of how often this is occurring, there were 4 separate questions this would apply to in the last day. (All by different users)

Comment: Um.... does the Stack Exchange API use OpenGL?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Not the Stack Exchange API. :)

Comment: See also: ["Is there something that can be done about old OpenGL questions?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166618/is-there-something-that-can-be-done-about-old-opengl-questions)

Comment: Your edit doesn't really change anything.  The only way to inform anyone of anything currently is via a comment.  If you want something more, it would have to be a feature request (which would likely be downvoted because the community doesn't want special cases for specific kinds of questions

Comment: @BradLarson thanks for the link. The suggestion of creating a tag for OpenGL 1.x seems like it would work well. Unfortunately, I don't currently have enough rep to do so myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are thoroughly convinced they are new to OpenGL and oblivious to the existence of the newer versions, and you think it would be beneficial for them to use the new versions, you can just leave a comment asking them if they're aware of later versions of OpenGL.

**That said, don't overdo this.**

Don't do this just because they're using an early OpenGL version, or may be new as well. They may be on a legacy project involving an earlier version, or attending University and being taught using an earlier version than was available at the time (like I was*), or may simply be using an earlier version by choice.

People should be able to ask questions about earlier OpenGL versions without being regularly pestered and followed around by "Are you aware of OpengL 4.x?" comments.

<sub>* The tutors made sure we were well aware there were more recent versions.</sub>

Comment: My school's AP Computer Science lab uses Java 7u25. Lots of fun to be had there.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the only way to really inform a user of anything is via a comment.

But when it comes right down to it, why do you assume the asker needs to be notified of anything.  There are plenty of programmers that are forced to use out-dated technologies in order to conform to older libraries or existing code.  So they might be fully aware that they are using an older version of the API but it might be by requirement rather than by choice.